# modify record in a file using c program

Tags: c, file-handling

I've written this c program to insert, view, modify and delete the records in a file. File name is emp.dat. The code for displaying, adding and deleting is working fine but the modify part is not working. The program asks to input details to modify but nothing gets updated/modified.
**The Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *outp,*inpt;
    char another,choice;
    struct emp
    {
        int emp_no,age;
        char name[40];
        float bs;
    };
    struct emp e;
    char empname[40];
    long int recsize;
    outp=fopen("emp.dat","r+");
    if(outp=='\0')
    {
        outp=fopen("emp.dat","w+");
        if(outp=='\0')
        {
            puts("cannot open file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    recsize=sizeof(e);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1.Add records\n");
        printf("2.List records\n");
        printf("3.Modify records\n");
        printf("4.Delete records\n");
        printf("0. exit\n");
        printf("Your choice\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        choice=getche();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':                           //code to add data
            .

            case '2':                        //code to display data

            case '3':                       //code to modify data
            another='Y';
            while(another=='Y')
            {
                printf("\nEnter name of employee to modify");
                scanf("%s",empname);
                rewind(outp);
                while(fread(&e,recsize,1,outp)==1)
                {
                    if(strcmp(e.name,empname)==0)
                    {
                        printf("\nenter new name,age & gs");
                        scanf("%d %s %d %f",&e.emp_no,&e.name,&e.age,&e.bs);
                        fseek(outp,-recsize,SEEK_CUR);
                        fwrite(&e,recsize,1,outp);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                printf("\nModify another record(Y/N)");
                fflush(stdin);
                another=getche();
            }
                        printf("\n\n");
            break;
            case '4':                         //code to delete data

            case '0':
            fclose(outp);
            printf("\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
As can be seen in output the name doesn't change from Zaid to Cow, so does the age and gs

Comment: You have posted quite a lot of code. You can increase the likelihood that someone will read it and try to help you if you create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this `if(outp=='\0')` should throw a warning even an error. just do this `if(!outp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should test the return values.

The prompt asks for `name,age & gs`, and you enter them as asked. However `scanf` is instructed to get an integer (`emp_no`) first (`"%d %s %d %f"`). Missing that it fails immediately and nothing gets updated.

The situation is easily detectable: `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions.