# Modifying a struct variable written on a file

Tags: c, file, structure

I'm working on this project, in which I need to track and modify user data consumption if the day and client already have a record on the file.
Everything seems to be working fine, the client consumption is tracked successfully, but it does not add it up to the previous value. Wondering if you guys can help me find the problem!

```
void CargaArchivoConsumo(char ArchivoConsumo[])
///Add clients struct to file
{
    stConsumo c;
    char opcion;
    int idCon=0, id=1;
    FILE *archi=fopen(ArchivoConsumo,"ab");
    if(archi)
    {
        id=idConsumoUnico("consumo.dat");
        do
        {
            c=cargaConsumo();
            c.id=id;
            idCon=BuscaIDConsumo("consumo.dat",c.fecha,c.idCliente);
///this function finds out if this particular user already has data consumption on this date, in which case it returns that consuption's ID.
            if (idCon!=0)
            {
                CargaConsumoExistente("consumo.dat",idCon,c.datosConsumidos);
///passes repeated record id and new data consumption onto this function, which SHOULD add it up to the previous record. 
                printf("\nYa se cargo un consumo para este usuario en esa fecha. El nuevo consumo se sumara al anterior\n");
            }
            else
            { 
/// If no other record is found, the new struct is written onto the file.
                fwrite(&c,sizeof(stConsumo), 1, archi);
                id++;
            }
            printf("\nPresione ESC para salir, cualquier tecla para continuar");
            fflush(stdin);
            opcion=getch();
            system("cls");
        }
        while(opcion!=ESC);
        fclose(archi);

    }
}

void CargaConsumoExistente(char ArchivoConsumo[],int idCon,int datos) 
///Adds new data on to the old record. Receives record ID and new data as parameter.
{
    stConsumo c;
    int found=0;
    FILE *archi= fopen(ArchivoConsumo, "r+");
    if(archi)
    {
        while (found==0 && fread(&c,sizeof(stConsumo),1,archi)>0)
        {///searching for that specific id on the file, and when found adds the new data onto the record.
            if(idCon==c.id)
            {
                c.datosConsumidos+=datos;           
                fwrite(&c,sizeof(stConsumo),1,archi);
                found=1;
            }
        }
        fclose(archi);
    }
}
```

Everything is working as expected, the latter function finds the record, and adds the data but it's not written onto the file.

Comment: Try opening the file in binary `fopen(ArchivoConsumo, "r+");` --> `"rb+"` - same as when writing.

Comment: Tip: `fwrite(&c, sizeof c, 1, archi);` easier to review than `fwrite(&c, sizeof(stConsumo), 1, archi);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Still not working! :(

Comment: "Still not working" is insufficient.  What was the input, what was expected, what was seen?  Best to post a [mcve].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sorry, i meant to say that changing the mode hasnt produced any changes at all. The file still finds the record, and adds it up inside the function, but fails to overwrite the previous data value(c.datosConsumidos) with the updated new one (c.datosConsumidos+=data). Thanks for responding!

Comment: Tomás Temperley, why do you expect an overwrite update?  Think of a file with 1 record that code successfully finds.  `fread(...,archi)` then `fwrite(...,archi);` should make a file of 2 records, no?  Research `fseek(), ftell()`.

Comment: In reviewing this link [Modify Record in File...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764129/modify-record-in-a-file-using-c-program) it looks like you need to perform an "fseek(...)" call to back up the file position.  Check out how the "fseek" call is immediately before the "fwrite" call.